# iOS Proper Way To Override initWithFrame With Custom Xib and View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib, nib

Right now, I am less than pleased with this hacky workaround I have created to try and create my custom view. It is initialized programmatically in another view controller with initWithFrame, and so I have overridden it in the code. This does not seem to be the proper way to initialize my view, but I am not sure what else to do.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OTGMarkerDetailView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
        [self setFrame:frame];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Without the setFrame method, the custom view always seems to be created at the top of window rather than at the coordinates I specified with CGRectMake.

I initialize the view in a method in my view controller here.

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    if (!self.detailView) {
        self.detailView = [[OTGMarkerDetailView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 55)];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:self.detailView];
    self.detailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSRange range = [self.startAddress rangeOfString:@","];
    NSString *mainAddress = [self.startAddress substringToIndex:range.location];
    NSString *subAddress = [self.startAddress substringFromIndex:range.location + 1];
    [self.detailView setLabelsWithMainAddress:mainAddress subAddress:subAddress];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.detailView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 513, 320, 55);
    }];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the best way of handling something like this is to use a class factory method:

```
+(instancetype)markerDetailView {
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OTGMarkerDetailView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
}
```

Then you create the view with:

```
self.detailView = [OTGMarkerDetailView markerDetailView];
```

Note that I also prefer to take a more type-safe approach to loading views from nib files:

```
+(instancetype)markerDetailView {
    for(OTGMarkerDetailView* view in [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OTGMarkerDetailView" owner:nil options:nil]) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[OTGMarkerDetailView class]]) {
            return view;
        }
    }

    NSAssert(false, @"Failed to load OTGMarkerDetailView");
    return nil;
}
```

If you need to use instances of your custom view in InterfaceBuilder you have to override `initWithCoder:` and `initWithFrame:`.  Since you're going to replace self, there's really no need to call `super` though:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    self = [[self class] markerDetailView];
    // I think this will work to inherit settable properties in IB
    if((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        // support any additional settable properties in IB
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: What if I needed to create this in interface builder? Should I set self to the return value of markerDetailView, since I would have to override initWithCoder and initWithFrame?

Comment: Yeah, if you're wanting to instantiate an instance of your custom class from Interface Builder AND create the custom view by loading from a nib file, then you'd have to override initWithCoder and initWithFrame, but in neither case would you bother calling super since you're just going to throw it away anyway.

Comment: And in that case I would probably still use the factory method and just wrap it in initWithCoder and initWithFrame.

Comment: I'm seeing some examples where they do [self addSubview:customView] at the end of their custom initializer. Is there any reason to do that if I can just set self to be the view itself?

Comment: Moving forward, towards IB 6 and it's support for IBDesignable, you'll probably want to avoid that metaphor, but I'm not sure how that will really play out.  Part of why right now I'm creating sub-views for my custom views in code, as much as I dislike doing that.

Comment: It appears we can't replace things in initWithCoder. It fails with "This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:". Does this mean there is no way to set self to the new view?

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't the `mapView` method just do what your `init` method does, i.e. pull the view out of its nib directly? In other words, why are you hiding from `mapView` the fact that the way to get an instance of this view is to load a nib? There is no reason to hide this fact.

Or, if you do want to hide that fact, why don't you write a convenience constructor as a class method for the view rather than misusing `initWithFrame`? e.g. `[OTGMarkerDetailView makeADetailView]`...

Comment: There's no reason to. I'll fix that - but as to everything else, is this an acceptable way of creating a custom view?

Comment: Generally speaking... no.  You're initializing your custom class and then immediately throwing it away by assigning a different instance to self.  A better solution would be a class factory method that loads the instance from the nib file.

Comment: Right, @David, that is what I meant by a convenience constructor as a class method.

Comment: Mostly I was answering his question about it being a reasonable approach and missed your constructor comment completely.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and I like your answer. I was just clarifying for the OP that we agree.